# Why laptop has 5v power when its off?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, hdmi, desktop-computer, display-adapter

I recently bought a PC. the motherboard is z690 p ddr5. I did not have a modern monitor so I also bought a mini HDMI to VGA adapter and used it to connect my pc to the monitor. the convertor itself has a USB power supply which is 5v current DC. I connected the wire to my laptop USB port. I have a pair of little desktop speakers and also my speakers power supply was connected to the laptop.
the weird thing is this:

the laptop was off and I turned on the pc and suddenly the speakers turned on too BY ITSELF. also the monitor started to switch off and on multiple times. now I'm panicked and I do not know how speakers went on while the laptop was off. I checked it like a thousand times and when laptop is off, speakers are off too until I connect the convertor's power supply to the laptop. what is going on here? did I messed up something?

Comment: https://www.cgdirector.com/what-is-erp-mode-erp-ready-in-bios/